# How to retrive loan borrowers from the database keeping retun months as columns names?

Tags: mysql, sql

In my database, loan returned is stored this way

```
---------+------------+------+-------------+------------+
borrower |loan_amount | rate | date_issued | instalment |
---------+------------+------+-------------+------------+
1        |       10000|    50| 2019-04-20  |           4|
---------+------------+------+-------------+------------+
2        |       20000|    50| 2019-04-20  |           3|
---------+------------+------+-------------+------------+
```

i want to achieve this output

```
---------+------------+-------+------+-------+------+
                      |   Installment per Months    |
---------+------------+-------+------+-------+------+
name     |       Total|     4 |    5 |     6 |    7 |
---------+------------+-------+-------------+-------+
John     |       15000|   3750|  3750|   3750|  3750|
---------+------------+-------+-------------+-------+
James    |       30000|  10000| 10000|  10000|     -|
---------+------------+-------+-------------+-------+
```

This is the logic behind.

1. The maximum number of installment is 4 and minimum is 1
2. Number of installment determine number of months loan should be returned and amount
3. total = (loan_amount + ((loan_amount*rate)/100))
4. if i want to retrive customers took loan on january, number of months should be 1, 2, 3, 4. For february should be 2, 3, 4, 5
5. at the bottom of each month total should be computed.

Comment: please dont over-tag. This has nothing to do with either `php` or `javascript`.

Comment: @Estern, can you explain the starting on Jan 1-4 and Feb 2-5, concept? How will you be selecting your results? What is your criteria conditions?

Comment: @blupointmedia my criteria condition is date loan issued, example if loan issued in January, the customer will require to return the loan on January, February, March, and April. if issued in February, return months will be February, March, April, and May